# How to handle the signal in operating system?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, signals, interrupt

When kernel sent a signal(e.g. SIGINT) to a process A.  there is a state that signal is pending.

My question is:

- Will process A being interrupted **immediately** if it does not stay
  in an uninterrupted state? Will signal handler wait for the time interrupt(or being scheduled by the scheduler)?
- Signal handler is a new process or  is just process A?

Comment: You might find 'man 7 signal' informative.

Answer (score 1):

The signal will be delivered to process when scheduler will choose to switch to that process. Instead of jumping to saved pc context it will jump to signal handler address (if installed). Of course this is the same process.

Comment: So, when process A is currently running then kernel sent a signal to process A, process A will not invoke the handler immediately, instead, wait for a while, due to scheduling? Is this about Mesa vs. Hoare semantics?

Comment: If we block/unblock a signal in child process,it will not change the state to block/unblock in parent process?

Comment: @yi_li For the SMP case, if a signal has been sent to process A, but it is currently running in user mode, an inter-processor interrupt will be sent to its CPU to cause it to enter kernel mode so its signal can be processed. See `kick_process()` in "kernel/sched/core.c".